# How can I integrate the TypeScript compiler into a VSCode language service extension?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code

I'm working on a custom programming language called [Storymatic](https://github.com/zsnout/storymatic) that compiles into TypeScript code. I want to make a VSCode extension that hooks into TypeScript's language service and sends completions from there.

So far I've tried to create a TypeScript language service and use that, but the TS language service keeps telling me that it can't find the source file for a specific file, even if the file is easily accessible via `fs.readFile`.

Here's the full example of the code I wrote:

```js
/** @type {string[]} */
  let files = [];
  let id = 0;
  let registry = ts.createDocumentRegistry();
  /** @type {ts.LanguageServiceHost} */
  let host = {
    getCompilationSettings() {
      return makeCompilerOptions();
    },
    getCurrentDirectory() {
      let folders = vscode.workspace.workspaceFolders;
      if (!folders) return "";
      return folders[0].uri.fsPath;
    },
    getDefaultLibFileName() {
      return ts.getDefaultLibFilePath({});
    },
    getScriptFileNames() {
      return files;
    },
    getTypeRootsVersion() {
      return id;
    },
    getScriptSnapshot(fileName) {
      let data = readFileSync(fileName, "utf-8");
      if (
        fileName.endsWith(".sm") ||
        fileName.endsWith(".story") ||
        fileName.endsWith(".storymatic")
      ) {
        return ts.ScriptSnapshot.fromString(
          transpile(compile(data), { typescript: true })
        );
      }
      return ts.ScriptSnapshot.fromString(data);
    },
    getScriptKind() {
      return ts.ScriptKind.TSX;
    },
    getScriptVersion() {
      return "";
    },
    readFile(fileName) {
      return readFileSync(fileName, "utf-8");
    },
    getNewLine() {
      return "\n";
    },
  };
  let acquireDocument = registry.acquireDocument.bind(registry);
  registry.acquireDocument = (fileName, ..._) => {
    if (
      fileName.endsWith(".sm") ||
      fileName.endsWith(".story") ||
      fileName.endsWith(".storymatic")
    ) {
      return compile(readFileSync(fileName, "utf-8"));
    }
    return acquireDocument(fileName, ..._);
  };
  vscode.languages.registerCompletionItemProvider(
    {
      language: "storymatic",
      scheme: "file",
    },
    {
      provideCompletionItems(document, position) {
        try {
          files = [document.uri.fsPath];
          id++;
          let service = ts.createLanguageService(host, registry);
          let items = service.getCompletionsAtPosition(
            document.uri.fsPath,
            document.getText(
              new vscode.Range(new vscode.Position(0, 0), position)
            ).length,
            undefined
          );
          console.log(items);
          return items?.entries.map((entry) => ({
            ...entry,
            kind: undefined,
            label: entry.name,
          }));
        } catch (/** @type {any} */ e) {
          // Added for debug purposes.
          return [
            { label: "" + e + "\n" + Object.keys(e) + "\n" + e.ProgramFiles },
          ];
        }
      },
    }
  );
```

Can somebody help me figure out why this isn't working?

Comment: But what's not working? What errors do you get? Unexpected behaviour?

Comment: Quote: "the TS language service keeps telling me that it can't find the source file for a specific file"